# Alembic: Include constraint to reject strings with character

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-like, alembic

I have a table that looks like this

```
> select * from mytable
  id        value
0  1  hello world
1  2  hello_world
2  3  hello+world
```

I'm trying to impose an alembic check constraint, where values in `value` cannot have the `:` character. How would I do this using an `alembic.op` object? What are the `upgrade()` and `downgrade()` functions?

Edit: The DB I'm using is Mysql.

Comment: How would this constraint be applied? On new data or on existing data somehow? What should be done if existing data violates said constraint? Adding constraints can also be – and is – a bit DB specific. What DB are you using?

Comment: @IljaEverilä All true. The assumption is that there is some data in the table, but they don't violate the constraint. The DB I'm using is Mysql.

Answer (score 6):

In this case, a check constraint works

```
def upgrade():
    op.create_check_constraint("constraint_name_here", "mytable", "value not like '%:%'")

def downgrade():
    op.drop_constraint("constraint_name_here", "mytable", type_="check")
```

But mysql doesn't support check constraints. ¯_(ツ)_/¯